# sicp 1.44 why it is a #<procedure>

Tags: iteration, scheme, sicp, function-composition

```
#lang planet neil/sicp

(define dx 0.00001)

(define (smooth-n f n)
  (repeat smooth f n))

(define (smooth f)
  (lambda (x) (/ (+ (f x) (f (- x dx)) (f (+ x dx))) 3)))

(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))

(define (repeat f g n) 
   (define (iter n result) 
     (if (< n 1) 
         result 
         (iter (- n 1) (compose f result)))) 
   (iter n (lambda (x) (g x))))

(define (square x) (* x x))

((smooth-n square 3) 2)     ---> #<procedure>
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the definition of `repeat`, which has an extra parameter. In the previous exercise it is required to define a function `repeat` that applied to a function *f* and a positive number *n* returns a new function, let call it *fn*, that applies *f* to its argument *n* times. `repeat` then could be defined as:

```
(define (repeat f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      f
      (compose f (repeat f (- n 1)))))
```

or, if you prefer a tail-recursive version, as:

```
(define (repeat f n)
  (define (iter n result)
    (if (= n 1)
        result
        (iter (- n 1) (compose f result))))
  (iter n f))
```

For instance:

```
((repeat square 2) 2)
16
```

since *fn* is the function that calculates the square of the square of its argument.

Given this definition, then `smooth-n` could be defined as:

```
(define (smooth-n f n)
  ((repeat smooth n) f))
```

that is: get the function obtained applying `smooth` *n* times, and apply it to `f`, so that the result is the *n-fold smoothed version of f*.

So that:

```
((smooth-n square 3) 2)
4.0000000002
```

Comment: emmm~ i think it complex， the start version is this~ thank you `

Answer (score 0):

According to your definitions we have

```
((smooth-n square 3) 2)
=
((repeat smooth square 3) 2)
=
((compose smooth (compose smooth (compose smooth square))) 2)
=
(smooth (smooth (smooth (square 2))))
=
(smooth (smooth (smooth 4)))
```

but you wanted to get `((smooth (smooth (smooth square))) 2)`. Redefining

```
(define (repeat f g n) 
   (define (iter n result) 
     (if (< n 1) 
         result 
         (iter (- n 1) (f result)))) 
   (iter (- n 1) (f g)))
```

takes care of it (returning `4.000000000266667`). But it's really non-idiomatic; you should go with the solution in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241441/849891) instead. (leaving this here for comparison).